# zend_db_select use with zend_db_table_abstract

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-select

I'm not sure how to do this: My `Post` model is extending `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` and I'm working on my homepage right now, where I want to show every post from the DB. The documentation says that `fetchAll()` and `fetchRow` are deprecated, and that I should use `Zend_Db_Select`. I've read through the manual, but I don't really see how this is used in combination with `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`? Or do I just make an instance and start writing queries 'out of nowhere'? Because I'd like to acces my data through my Model...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not deprecated, the use on them is the one that changed, for example, before you could pass a where clause and a order clause, the correct way to do that is use a Select:

```
public function getNewOrdersByDate()
{
     $Select = $this->select();
     $Select->where('status=?', 'new')->order('created ASC');

     return $this->fetchAll($Select);
}
```

Comment: i.e. Zend_Db_Table_Abstract has a select() method which will return a Zend_Db_Select object which will SELECT from whichever table the Zend_Db_Table_Abstract instance represents.

Comment: are joins possible then? i don't see how if it only selects from the table it represents... thanks!

Comment: No, in that case you must do something like: $Select = $this->getAdapter()->select() and then use $this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($Select); The problem is that using a join leaves a Zend_Db_Table_Row with more columns that it has. In the manual there is a example to use it, or use a readonly object.